# Typescript Window Setting Variable

Tags: window, typescript

I have part of typescript code

```
  var root = window['appPath'] 
  window.location.replace(root + '.... some url
```

Is the variable windows part of typescript? How do I assign it? Is it a key/value and what can I store in it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the variable windows part of typescript

Its a part of `browser` spec : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

TypeScript defines these common globals for you in a file `lib.d.ts` : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/bin/lib.d.ts

> How do I assign it?

You *shouldn't* and actually browsers will not let you.

> Is it a key/value and what can I store in it?

All JavaScript objects (I'm being lose here) act like key/value stores. The only allowed key is `string`. Value can be any other JavaScript object.

That said. **DONT PUT STUFF ON WINDOW. MILLIONS OF KITTENS WILL DIE**